# Prove equivalence between properties of relations using fixpoint calculus

Tags: relations, fixed-point-theorems, lattice-orders, fixed-points

### The problem

Let $a$ be a binary endorelation of some countable set $S$, i.e. $a \subseteq S \times S$ .

I need to show that the following properties are equivalent:

1. $ (a^*)^{-1} ; a^* \subseteq a^* ; (a^*)^{-1} $
2. $(a \cup a^{-1})^* = a^* ; (a^*)^{-1}$

Where $(-)^*$ is the transitive-reflexive closure, $(-)^{-1}$ is the converse relation ($x R y \iff y R^{-1}x$) and $;$ is the [usual relation composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations).

### Fixed point induction

I need to use Fixed Point Induction (Knaster-Tarski) in the proof, at least for the part (1) $\implies$ (2). Given that $a^* = \mu x . id_S \cup (a ; x)$, by Knaster-Tarski if we can show that $a^* ; (a^*)^{-1}$ is a pre-fixed point of the function $F(x) = id_S \cup (a \cup a^{-1}) ; x$ we will have also proven $(a \cup a^{-1})^* \leq a^* ; (a^*)^{-1}$. That is:

$$ id_S \cup (a \cup a^{-1}); (a^* ; (a^{*})^{-1}) \subseteq a^* ; (a^{*})^{-1} \implies  (a \cup a^{-1})^* \leq a^* ; (a^*)^{-1}$$

What I then noticed is that, since it is evident that $id_S \subseteq a^* ; (a^{*})^{-1}$, we only need to prove:

$$ (a \cup a^{-1}); (a^* ; (a^{*})^{-1}) \subseteq a^* ; (a^{*})^{-1}$$

From which I'm absolutely stuck. I would appreciate even only a proof of the above formula, not necessarily the whole solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first prove how (1) implies (2). Let $a$ be an endorelation on $A$ and assume $(a \cup a^{-1})^* = a^*; {a^{-1}}^*$. To prove that $a$ satisfies (1) it is now enough to prove ${a^{-1}}^*;a^* \leq (a \cup a^{-1})^*$. By the Kleene star being monotonic, hence laxly join preserving, we have $a^* \cup {a^{-1}}^* \leq (a \cup a^{-1})^*$. We now show that ${a^{-1}}^*;a^* \leq a^* \cup {a^{-1}}^*$. Let $t {{a^{-1}}^*;a^*} s$. That is, there exist two finite integers $m$, $n$:
$$ t\,\, {\underbrace{a^{-1} ; ... ; a^{-1}}_n;{\underbrace{a ; ... ; a}_m}} \,\,s $$
We now distinguish three cases. If $m > n$ then $ t\,\, {a^*}\,\, s$, by repeated cancellation of $a$ and its converse. Similarly, if $m < n$ then $t\,\, {{a^{-1}}^*}\,\, s$. Finally, if $m = n$, we have $t\,\, {id}\,\, s$. We conclude by the following observation:
$$
  \begin{matrix}
  a^* \leq a^* \cup {a^{-1}}^*\\
  {a^{-1}}^* \leq a^* \cup {a^{-1}}^*\\
  id \leq a^* \cup {a^{-1}}^*
  \end{matrix} \text{ implies } t \,\, {a^* \cup {a^{-1}}^*} \,\, s 
  $$
In conclusion:
$$ {a^{-1}}^*;a^* \leq a^* \cup {a^{-1}}^* \leq (a \cup a^{-1})^* = a^*; {a^{-1}}$$

We now show that (1) implies (2). Assume ${a^{*}}^{-1} ; a^{*} \leq a^{*} ; {a^{*}}^{-1}$. In order to prove that $a$ is (2) we need to show the following inequalities:
$$
 a^*; {a^{-1}}^* \leq (a \cup a^{-1})^*
 $$
$$
(a \cup a^{-1})^* \leq a^*; {a^{-1}}^*
 $$

- By the monotonicity of the Kleene star the following holds: $$a^*; {a^{-1}}^* \leq (a \cup a^{-1})^* ; (a \cup a^{-1})^*$$
  And by $R^*;R^* \leq R^*$ we conclude: $a^*; {a^{-1}}^* \leq (a \cup a^{-1})^*$
- By fixed point induction, as $b^* = \mu x .id \cup b;x$, we have:
  $$ id \cup (a \cup a^{-1}); a^*; {a^{-1}}^* \leq a^*; {a^{-1}}^* \implies (a \cup a^{-1})^* \leq a^*; {a^{-1}}^* $$
  Firstly we have $id \leq id ; id \leq a^* ; {a^{-1}}^*$ hence we only need to prove:
  $$ (a \cup a^{-1}); a^*; {a^{-1}}^* \leq a^*; {a^{-1}}^* $$
  Which can be proven as follows:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
   (a \cup a^{-1}); a^*; {a^{-1}}^* &= a ; a^*; {a^{-1}}^*  \cup a^{-1} ; a^*; {a^{-1}}^* \\
   &\leq a^*; {a^{-1}}^*  \cup a^{-1} ; a^*; {a^{-1}}^* &{a; a^* \leq a^*\text{ and monot. };} \\
   &\leq a^*; {a^{-1}}^*  \cup {a^{-1}}^* ; a^*; {a^{-1}}^* &{a^{-1} \leq {a^{-1}}^*\text{ and monot. };} \\
   &\leq a^*; {a^{-1}}^*  \cup {a^{-1}}^* ; a^*; {a^{-1}}^* &{\text{Hp.}} \\
   &\leq a^*; {a^{-1}}^*  \cup {a}^* ; {a^{-1}}^*; {a^{-1}}^* &{\text{Hp.}} \\
   &\leq a^*; {a^{-1}}^*  \cup {a}^* ; {a^{-1}}^* &{R ; R \leq R} \\
   &=  a^*; {a^{-1}}^*
  \end{aligned}
  $$